# Cmake with bitbake recipe

Tags: cmake, openembedded, bitbake

I am trying to build an yocto image with my own package. I have OpenCV code on github which uses cmake.

I trying to write a recipe for it and facing lot of errors. Can any one give some hints on what functions or parameters to include in my recipe. My recipe looks as following

```
DESCRIPTION = "cameracapture application" 
SECTION = "examples" 
LICENSE = "CLOSED" 
PR = "r0" 

DEPENDS += "opencv"

SRC_URI = "git://https://github.com/zafrullahsyed/cameracapture.git;protocol=https;tag=v0.1"

EXTRA_OECMAKE=""

do_configure() { 
 cmake ../ 
} 

inherit pkgconfig cmake
```

I followed these tutorials to write my recipe with cmake but in vain:
[Bitbake Player recipe](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/wiki/Cross_Compile_Player_with_Openembedded_and_BitBake#Player_Recipe)

[Cmake-Bitbake-QT](http://cor-net.org/hello-world-in-qt-using-cmake-and-openembedded/3/)

Comment: Could you please mention the errors?

Comment: Also, you should not use PR anymore.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The correct way of writing own recipes with cmake as follows:

```
DESCRIPTION = "cameracapture application" 
SECTION = "examples" 
LICENSE = "CLOSED" 
PR = "r0" 

DEPENDS = "opencv"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/zafrullahsyed/cameracapture.git;protocol=https;tag=v0.1"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit pkgconfig cmake

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 cameracapture ${D}${bindir}
}
```

Previously I didn't add `do_install` that's the reason yocto downloads the recipe but unable to include it Image.

Comment: do_install is not necessary, see elmsfu's answer

Comment: Like the previous comment, `do_install` isn't necessary. The `cmake.bbclass` will run ` oe_runmake 'DESTDIR=${D}' install` by default.

Answer (score 22):

If the CMakeLists.txt uses the `install` command then bitbake will do the install for you and you won't need to define you own do_install.

```
install(TARGETS cameracapture DESTINATION bin)
```

Comment: do you means there is no need to add `do_install()` in the recipe?

Comment: @hukeping You don't have to add do_install() task. install instruction as pointed in answer has to be added in CMakeLists.txt. do_install() from cmake base class will make use of "make install".

Answer (score 6):

add the source directory in your recipe.

example
`S = "${WORKDIR}/cameracapture`

S is the source code path where your CMakeList.txt.

any how your are inheriting the cmake bbclass in your recipe, so it will take care of all configure , compile and install functionalities.

after doing this you can remove you do_configure function in the above recipe also.

you can add your make options if any to the below macro (as you kept empty).
example

`EXTRA_OECMAKE = "all"`

Comment: can you explain me about do_install. I too have the similar kind of problem while installing binaries. please see the below question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508048/do-install-error-while-running-custom-bitbake-in-poky-build