# do_install error while running custom bitbake in poky build

Tags: linux, makefile, texas-instruments, bitbake

I am using latest poky-am335x to build simple helloworld application. With some workaround I can able to compile the application. I am doing lot of trails to install binaries but build is throwing error.

error log :

```
DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-32', 'arm-common', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'arm-linux', 'arm-linux-gnueabi', 'common']
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install
NOTE: make -j 4 DESTDIR=/home/pis1kor/workspace/poky-am335x/build/tmp/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/helloworld-1.0-r0/image install
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: Function failed: do_install (see /home/pis1kor/workspace/poky-am335x/build/tmp/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/helloworld-1.0-r0/temp/log.do_install.29583 for further information)
```

Bitbake file :

```
DESCRIPTION = "Simple helloworld application"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
PR = "r0"
SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.tar"

do_compile () {
        make -C ${WORKDIR}/helloworld all
}


do_install() {
        oe_runmake install DESTDIR=${D}
}


#do_install() {
#       oe_runmake install DESTDIR=${D}
#       make -C ${WORKDIR}/helloworld/ install
#       oe_runmake 'DESTDIR=${D}' install
#       cp -f ${WORKDIR}/helloworld/helloworld ${WORKDIR}/image
#       oe_runmake install ${WORKDIR}/helloworld
#       make -C ${WORKDIR}/helloworld install
#       install -d ${D}${bindir}/ ZZ
#}

inherit autotools gettext
```

Makefile :

```
IDIR = ./include
CC = arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a     -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a8 --sysroot=/home/pis1kor/workspace/poky-am335x/build/tmp/sysroots/am335x-evm
CFLAGS = -I$(IDIR)
LIBS = -lm

FILES = ./src/helloworld.c
OUT_EXE = helloworld

INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c

INSTALL_DATA = ${INSTALL} -m 644



all: $(FILES)
        $(CC) -o $(OUT_EXE) $(FILES) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

install:
        $(INSTALL_DATA) -C  helloworld ../image
#       sudo cp ./helloworld ../image/

clean:
        rm -f *.o helloworld
```

The commented lines are kept like that because just to mansion all the trails I tried with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic differences are the below.

```
S = "${WORKDIR}/helloworld/"
EXTRA_OEMAKE = 'all -C ${S}'
```

***"EXTRA_OEMAKE"*** is the key macro which I didn't used before.

I have changed the bitbake file helloworld.bb file like below.

```
DESCRIPTION = "Simple helloworld application"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
PR = "r0"

S = "${WORKDIR}/helloworld/"
EXTRA_OEMAKE = 'all -C ${S}'

SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.tar"

inherit autotools gettext
```