# How to create cmake recipes in Yocto?

Tags: git, cmake, yocto

I like to figure out how to create a recipe which is downloaded from git and build by using a make file.
For example:

the [g3logger](https://github.com/KjellKod/g3log) (git https://github.com/KjellKod/g3log.git)

How must be the recipe "bb" file looks like?

Comment: Similar question has been already responded in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382407/cmake-with-bitbake-recipe

Comment: there is still an problem that the g++ compiler does not find the c++ headers. It breaks when cmake tries to compile "#include <string>"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, this is a problem in g3log (which other programs also likely have).  If you open up 'Build.cmake' and look around lines 53-56 you see:

```
   ELSE()
       set(PLATFORM_LINK_LIBRIES rt)
       set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -rdynamic -Wunused -std=c++11 -pthread -D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP -D_GLIBCXX_USE_SCHED_YIELD")
   ENDIF()
```

Which overrides what OpenEmbedded has placed into toolchain.cmake.  If you change this instead to:

```
       set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -rdynamic -Wunused -std=c++11 -pthread -D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP -D_GLIBCXX_USE_SCHED_YIELD")
```

it will now inherit the flags that OpenEmbedded wants you to have such as --sysroot= so that standard includes are found.

Comment: Wow. Great catch! This saved me a whole lot of trouble

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your comment:
Maybe it's an error from your Makefile? 
For string it should be:

```
#include <string.h>
```

or

```
#include <cstring>
```

You can also show logs for specific task like do_compile, so we'll have deeper insight.

Tips on debugging tasks in bitbake: [Yocto Ref Manual - Debugging build failures](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#usingpoky-debugging)

Comment: I think it's somewhere in my "g3log.bb" file. I give you a listing:
###################
SUMMARY = "g3log"
SECTION = "sek4"

DEPENDS ="boost"

SRCREV = "db23383aeaa9704f466422d3cb6ea527c2434290"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/KjellKod/g3log.git"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit pkgconfig cmake

LICENSE = "LICENSE"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${WORKDIR}/git/LICENSE;md5=7246f848faa4e9c9fc0ea91122d6e680"
###################

Comment: The recipe doesn't seem to be broken (I can only suggest placing LICENSE variables before the SRCREV and DEPENDS after S). Please show the output from: 'bitbake -c compile -f g3log'.

Comment: ok done!
the (shortened)log: 
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++   -Dg3logger_shared_EXPORTS -Wall -rdynamic -Wunused -std=c++11 -pthread -D_GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP -D_GLIBCXX_USE_SCHED_YIELD -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -DNDEBUG -fPIC -I/src -I/example    -o CMakeFiles/g3logger_shared.dir/src/logcapture.cpp.o -c /src/logcapture.cpp
| In file included from /src/g3log/logmessage.hpp:13:0,
|                  from /src/logmessage.cpp:9:
| /src/g3log/loglevels.hpp:25:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory

Comment: I deleted  the paths. It seems that the include paths of the std. libs are getting lost. Maybe set them manually - do you know how?