# What is the "S" variable in a Yocto Bitbake recipe, and when do I need to set it?

Tags: git, cmake, yocto, bitbake

I just added a new Bitbake recipe to wrap my CMake git repo, that's also in development. But I get an error saying that it can't find the `CMakeLists.txt` file. I can confirm that the latest git repo/branch is getting cloned, and it has the `CMakeLists.txt` file there, so I'm at a loss on what to do. I'm using Dunfell Yocto.

I looked at some [other CMake example recipes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19366665/2125392). One suggested adding this `S` line to the recipe:

```
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/zafrullahsyed/cameracapture.git;protocol=https;tag=v0.1"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit pkgconfig cmake
```

What does this `S`variable do? And when do you generally need to set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`S` is used to point to source files that are unpacked with `do_unpack` into the recipe's `WORKDIR`. Check [this](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/overview-manual/concepts.html#source-fetching) for source fetching and unpacking process details.

The default value of `S` is `${WORKDIR}/${BPN}-${PV}`:

Example: `example_0.1.bb` , `S` would be: `example-0.1` folder inside `WORKDIR`.

Now, what you MUST keep in mind that sources are not usually unpacked in `S` by default, unless you are unpacking a compressed file that has the same name value as `S`, example:

```
SRC_URI = "https://somewebsite/example-0.1.zip"
```

Default unpacking destination differs with each source type (`SRC_URI` input type):

- `git://repo` will be unpacked under `${WORKDIR}/git`
- `file://somefile` will be unpacked directly under `${WORKDIR}`

These are the default values of course, Yocto provides `parameters` to control the unpacking process. Parameters are set in `SRC_URI` as follows:

```
SRC_URI = "scheme://URL;param1=val1;param2=val2;..."
```

For example if you want to change that you can use:

- `subdir`: to specify another folder to unpack the sources in
- `destsuffix`: for `git` this is the path to use for git checkout, default is `git/` as I mentioned above.

In your case you don't need to set these parameters.

Now, the other important part that you need to understand is:

- Every bitbake task works in some one or more directories and it is specified with the `dirs` flag.

So, in your case, `do_configure` that is `inherit`ed from `cmake.bbclass` needs to find `CMakeLists.txt` from `S`.

Here is a snipped of `cmake.bbclass:do_configure`:

```
# Path to the CMake file to process.
OECMAKE_SOURCEPATH ??= "${S}"
...

cmake_do_configure() {
      ...
      cmake \
          ${OECMAKE_GENERATOR_ARGS} \
          $oecmake_sitefile \
          ${OECMAKE_SOURCEPATH} \   <======== AS YOU CAN SEE HERE
          ...
```

As you can notice, `OECMAKE_SOURCEPATH` points to where `CMakeLists.txt` is. Bitbake assumes that it is under `S`. So if you have your `CMakeLists.txt` under subdirectory in your project (example: `yourproject/sources/CMakeLists.txt`) then imagine that `yourproject`'s content will be unpacked under `S` which is `${WORKDIR}/git` so you can change `OECMAKE_SOURCEPATH` as follows:

```
inherit cmake
OECMAKE_SOURCEPATH = "${S}/sources"
```

That was just an example to understand more `cmake.bbclass`

So, your git project will be unpacked under `${WORKDIR}/git`, that's why you need to change the default value of `S` to that new location where your `CMakeLists.txt` is located.

Another side point here to mention is that, there is another value called `${B}` that points to the build directory that will hold the build output, because some projects support generating the output in different directory like `cmake` and some advanced `Makefile` projects like the Linux kernel.

By default: `S = "${B}"`, so the build will happen in the same directory. That's why in the `base.bbclass` which is the class that is `inherit`ed automatically for all recipes to provide all recipe's tasks from `do_fetch` to `do_deploy` sets the directory for main tasks as `B`:

```
do_configure[dirs] = "${B}"
do_compile[dirs] = "${B}"
do_install[dirs] = "${B}"
```

In your case, `cmake.bbclass` changes `B` to: `${WORKDIR}/build` as follows:

```
B = "${WORKDIR}/build"
```

So, now let's print the big picture:

- You `inherit` `cmake`: this will override the orignal `base.bbclass:do_configure, do_compile and do_install` with the new ones to support `cmake` project
- `do_configure` by default work in `B`
- `cmake` class changes `B` to `${WORKDIR}/build` to separate the output
- `cmake`'s `do_configure` runs `cmake` command on `OECMAKE_SOURCEPATH` which points to `S`
- Since `do_configure` works in `B`, then it will find `CMakeLists.txt` in `S` and uses it to generate output in `B`
- `do_compile` works as well in `B` so it will continue with the compilation process
- and so on ...

To understand more with a practical example, check my workshop on that here:

- [Details you should know about the recipe’s working directory: Part I](https://yoctoleef.xyz/2023/06/08/details-you-should-know-about-the-recipes-working-directory/)
- [Details you should know about the recipe’s working directory: Part II](https://yoctoleef.xyz/2023/07/27/details-you-should-know-about-the-recipes-working-directory-part-ii/)

Side note: my TLS certificate expired so https will warn you :))

Comment: This is super helpful. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the in the Yocto Project Reference Manual v3.1.28, The variable ${S} is:

> The location in the Build Directory where unpacked recipe source code resides. By default, this directory is ${WORKDIR}/${BPN}-${PV}, where ${BPN} is the base recipe name and ${PV} is the recipe version. If the source tarball extracts the code to a directory named anything other than ${BPN}-${PV}, or if the source code is fetched from an SCM such as Git or Subversion, then you must set S in the recipe so that the OpenEmbedded build system knows where to find the unpacked source.

Here is the link to the Glossary entry:
[Ref Variables: Term S](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/3.1.28/ref-manual/ref-variables.html?highlight=srcrev#term-S)

I think the rule of thumb here is that whenever the `SRC_URI` is set to a git repository, you must set

```
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
```